# How to display only single column of mysql table in Tableview (Javafx)?

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

**Hi, I have tried the following code to display only one column of mysql table in tableview of javafx, but it's not working.**

```
TableView table = new TableView();
private static ObservableList<ObservableList> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("Username");
table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);
firstNameCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(1));
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Username"));

Connection conn_mysql;
conn_mysql = DBConnector.connect();
String SQL = "SELECT Username_name from Accounts";
ResultSet rs = conn_mysql.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

while (rs.next()) { 
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    row.add(rs.getString("Username_name"));
    data.add(row);
}

table.setItems(data);
```

Comment: Can you be more explanatory adding what exactly is not working? If you are looking at exceptions, add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: Column Heading Username is working, but the row values i.e getString("Username_name")  is not displaying in tableview.

Comment: Rows [User1]
Rows [User2]
Rows [User3]
Rows [User4]
Data [[User1], [User2], [User3], [User4]]

Comment: Have you tried to rename your firstNameCol to new TableColumn("Username_name")? As i read the oracle docs for [PropertyValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) it would search for this as your not using a pojo for your username

Comment: Yes I have tried that too..

Comment: Have you tried to directly add the syl data to the data variabel? 'data.add(rs.getString("Username_name"))'

Comment: not suitable method found for add(String)

Comment: You have to change the ObservableList private static ObservableList<ObservableList> data... to private static ObservableList<String> data...

Comment: @Inge Please stop guessing.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your code doesn't work**

The `cellValueFactory` is a function that maps the item representing each row to the value that should be displayed in the cell for that row and that column. This function is represented as a [`Callback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html). [`PropertyValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) is a convenience implementation that is equivalent either to

```
cellData -> cellData.getValue().xxxProperty()
```

or

```
cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getXxx())
```

where `xxx` is the name specified in the `PropertyValueFactory` and `cellData` is a [`CellDataFeatures`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html).

---

**Improving your code** (for clarity as to what is happening and to help fix it)

Your code would be much improved if you didn't use raw types. I.e. you should do

```
TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<>();
private static ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Username");
```

Here you actually specify the types represented by the `TableView` and `TableColumn`. Each row is represented by an `ObservableList<String>` and the value in each cell in the column is represented by a `String`.

Now it should be clear why your code doesn't work. The `PropertyValueFactory` gets the value for a row, in effect

```
ObservableList<String> row  = ... ;
```

and tries to call either

```
row.UsernameProperty()
```

or

```
row.getUsername()
```

to get the value for the column. Neither of those methods exist.

---

**Fixing the problem**

So you should just set the `cellValueFactory` to something that looks up the first element of the list representing the row:

```
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    ObservableList<String> rowValue = cellData.getValue();
    String cellValue = rowValue.get(0);
    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellValue);
});
```

Comment: firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().Username_nameProperty());

Comment: For above code , error message is shown: cannot find symbol method getValue()

Comment: In my code you get that error message? The code you posted in the first comment won't work for exactly the reasons explained in the answer.